# running jest through config gives error

Tags: jestjs

I am trying to run jest by specifying a configuration file.  The command line I am using is

```
"test": "jest -—config jest/jest.config.js",
```

My jest.config.js file looks like the following

```
module.exports = {
  bail: true,
  verbose: true,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|jpg|png)$': '<rootDir>/empty-module.js-'
  }
};
```

However when I run the npm command I keep getting the following error

validateCLIOptions.js:62
    throw createCLIValidationError(unrecognizedOptions, allowedOptions);
    ^

←[31m←[1m←[1m●←[1m Unrecognized CLI Parameters←[22m:

Answer (score 0):

You need another `--` otherwise the parameter would send to `npm` not to `jest`

```
"jest -- --config jest/jest.config.js",
```